# Add pages to a web part automatically SharePoint 2010

Tags: web-part

Hi i wanted to add a web part on the homepage of the site which should add up the links of the pages which are added to the site automatically once the page has been created is this possible with jquery or javascript since we don't go for server side solutions in our environment. will this be possible with content query or editor web-parts. I am using SharePoint 2010.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to display all the links to pages on the homepage, or just display the number of page links?

Comment: @ clk i want to show the links of pages in a web part

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a Content Query Web Part. Add the Content Query Web Part to the page where you want to display a list of the links to other pages. Then open the web part properties and expand the `Query` section. For the `Source:` section, select the `Show items from all sites in this site collection` option. Then in the `List Type:` section, select `Pages Library.` Here's a screenshot of the property configuration:

[image: Content Query Web Part properties]

At the bottom of the web part settings pane click `Apply` then `Ok`.

Comment: i tried this already but my scenario is I have to get only particular template based pages not all of them this option in CQWP gives all the links in the pages library I am looking to bring only work-space template based pages not all.Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the work-space **site** template? Or do you have a custom created work-space **page** template? If you have a custom created **page** content type, then you can choose that under the `Content Type:` option in the `Query` section of the CQWP.

Comment: Its just work-space site template

Comment: Ok, with that additional information then it doesn't look like there's an OOTB way to do what you want. You can use a web service to get all the site templates and filter by the specific template you want, but I'm not completely sure how to do that. It looks like you could also use the Table of Contents Web Part and then develop a custom XSL stylesheet to get just those sites. Check out this article for more info http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3884/webpart-to-display-list-of-subsites

Comment: I have gone through that site and got all the sub-sites but I am not sure on how to get the particular template based sites. Thanks for your brief responses.

Comment: I found this that may be helpful but I'm not sure if it will apply to SharePoint 2010 http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/48020/get-available-site-templates-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api.aspx

Comment: I think i have to use Jqeury or java script to pull the required templates to show up but am not a pro in either of the scripting. I will look into it and will give a shot of using this..thanks clk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26980/discussion-between-user2314241-and-clk).